# Laravel call ajax function which requires authentication

Tags: ajax, laravel

Problem is when user finished his work don't log out and leaves open page which requires authentication.

Next day he comes obviously session is lost and he is logged out, but he don't realize that and uses his open window where ajax functionality is.

How can I get right response to alert him to logout or redirect to login page, because I can't access method in where I could return response that user is logged out.

For example in Codeigniter I can still access my route check if user is logged in and return right response but I don't know how to do this in Laravel in the right way.

I am using ajax to save settings like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('save.settings') }}",
    dataType: "json",
    data:  { "data" : postData,  "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    success:function(data_response){
        console.log(data_response); // user is logged out
        if(data.respone.user_logged){
          //continue 
        }else{
          window.location = '/login'; // force to login window
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If the route requires authentication and the user is not authenticated then laravel sends an error response of 401 (or maybe 403). At any rate, the `success` callback will not be called so you need to also specify an `error` callback and check the error startus code and if it is a 401 or 403 redirect to login

Comment: If session is not active then in ajax request you will get Unauthenticated/Unauthorized text from server with error code as @apokryfos mentioned

Comment: thanks for responses, just found the way catch that response using :
,error: function (request, status, error) {
     console.log(request.responseText);
     console.log(status);
     console.log(error);
    }
problem solved.